# RBAC - Should I put permissions in the DB or hard code them?

Tags: security, authorization, rbac

My DB schema has business objects in it, for example those three tables that describe patient/doctor relations:

```
doctor        doctor_patient_relation       patient
---------     -----------------------       ----------
id        <-  doctor_id                |--> id
name: str     patient_id --------------|    name: str
              is_main_doctor: bool
```

The rules are:

- You can `patient:view` and `patient:edit` if you are a doctor with a doctor/patient relation with that patient.
- You can `patient:delete` if you are the main doctor for that patient.

For my RBAC system, should I just hard code the rules in my system? Like so for example (pseudo code):

```
route.DELETE('/patient/delete/:patientId', (req) => {

  if (req.user.hasRole('doctor') && req.user.patientRelations.where(patientRel.patient_id == req.patientId)) {
    return true; // can perform action
   } 
   else return false; // unauthorized
});
```

**OR** should I make RBAC tables for permissions and keep a parallel record of permissions for each doctor/patient relations? And do that with all the other business objects in my DB? Example:

```
permission_name | resource_id     |  user_id
--------------- | --------------- | -------------
patient:delete  | <id of patient> | <id of doctor>
```

It just seems to me that keeping parallel records of permissions will explose the number of rows in my DB and will be hard to maintain. However, it also provides an abstraction between the permissions module and the business modules.

I've been pondering about this for a few days now and I'm quite unsure which is the best option. What do you think?

Comment: Use externalized authorization / attribute-based access control

Comment: @DavidBrossard Thanks for the hint. I'll definitely check it out! Just spent a few minutes looking into XACML and Axiomatic. Interesting stuff